# 一週間前までに Meaning

Tags: meaning, translation, sentence, time

The full sentence is

> 見学を希望する場合は、一週間前までに担当者を通じて申し込んでください。

I want to know this 一週間前までに meaning. I tried thinking and came up with "within one week before (the deadline which is not mentioned)" but I'm not sure if it's correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at the different parts:

- までに usually refers to a hard deadline (e.g. "until ... at the latest")
- 見学 means (learning/training by) watching, for example watching a training session
- 一週間前 is to be understood as one week before the intended date of 見学 (e.g. watching the training session).

Putting it all together:

> 見学を希望する場合は、一週間前までに担当者を通じて申し込んでください。
>   For those wishing to watch [a training session / a lesson], please get in touch with the contact person at least a week in advance.

(You will have to adapt the translation of 見学 depending on the context.)